# Lydia gone after Containment quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After finishing the Containment quest Lydia was taken over (controlled) by a mage. How can I get her back?

---

Thanks for your answers guys. It really had me stumped.

I now also believe she must have died during the hectic fight and reanimated by a mage, seeing as she was no longer just 'lydia', but 'that guys lydia'.

I'll load an older game and try it again.

Comment: I actually had the same issue. I know she was alive after the anomalies were killed, but sometime between that and getting the next stage of the quest she disappeared. I keep hoping she'll turn up at some point :-/

Comment: Please don't edit comments into your question. Post it as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect Lydia wasn't 'controlled' by a Mage: She was probably killed and reanimated as an undead. If this is the case all her stuff should reside in a dust pile, as she would die again when you killed the mage. If this is the case then the only way to get her back is to use console commands to bring her back to life.

I just read over the [Containment Quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Containment) in detail: You don't fight any mages in it, just a bunch of Magical Anomalies. Are you sure this is the quest you are referring to?